# unbind jquery to copt the output text

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, unbind

I am trying to unbind on a certain element - #result

the output box has the ID of #result

because i have ("input, BODY")

the bind will happen on body - keyup click and mousemove

i need it so when ever you click the #result box it wil not bind or unbind

you can see the example here http://5t5t5t5t5t5t5.weebly.com/

click generate widget which will show the result box the issue is i can not highlight the text inside the result box because the event is happening

```js
// text output    
$("input, body").bind("keyup click mousemove", function() {
  $("#result").text(
    '<div class="section-title-box animated fadeInUp wow animated" data-wow-delay="0.2s">' +
    '<h6 style="color:#' + $("#h6_color").val() +
    ';">' + $("#h6_title_text").val() +
    '</h6>' +
    '<h2 style="color:#' + $("#h2_color").val() +
    ';">' + $("#h2_title_text").val() +
    '</h2>' +
    '<hr style="border:2px solid #' + $("#hr_color").val() +
    ';width:' + $("#hr_width").val() +
    'px;">' +
    '<p>' + $("#widg_content").val() + '</p>' +
    '</div>'
  );

  $("#result").unbind('keyup click mousemove', '#result');

});
```

any help greatly appreciated - thanks Lee

Comment: try $("body").off('keyup click mousemove', '#result');

Comment: thanks for your answer unfortunately it didnt work  $("body").off('keyup click mousemove', '#result');

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Hi, version jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: hmm.. can you provide the html?

Comment: to use .off do you have to specify .on before hand ?

Comment: <textarea id="result"></textarea>

Comment: use on instead of bind

Comment: is this the whole html? can you provide the css as well, a jsfiddle would be great

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/rx5xvec8/1/

Comment: hey thanks for the fiddle :) the issue is that i can not highlight the text in the result box , so a user can highlight the text and copy and paste the html result - if this makes sense :) the ussue is still there on the fiddle

Comment: so need to highlight the text with blue highlight and then be able to copy

Comment: i can highlight the text in the textarea and copy it as well

Comment: ive tried in FF and Chrome, the blue highlight flickers off after a second, so can not copy, so you can highlight and copy ok ?

Comment: i can on chrome. let me try on firefox. it stays if u dont move the mouse

Comment: how about this http://jsfiddle.net/rx5xvec8/2/ ??

Answer (score 0):

This Code Did The Trick :)

```js
function handleClick(event) {
  $("#result").text(
    '<div class="section-title-box animated fadeInUp wow animated" data-wow-delay="0.2s">' +
    '<h6 style="color:#' + $("#h6_color").val() +
    ';">' + $("#h6_title_text").val() +
    '</h6>' +
    '<h2 style="color:#' + $("#h2_color").val() +
    ';">' + $("#h2_title_text").val() +
    '</h2>' +
    '<hr style="border:2px solid #' + $("#hr_color").val() +
    ';width:' + $("#hr_width").val() +
    'px;">' +
    '<p>' + $("#widg_content").val() + '</p>' +
    '</div>'
  );
}

$('input, body').on('keyup mousedown', handleClick);

$('input, body').off('click', '#result', handleClick);
```

thanks for all your help https://stackoverflow.com/users/4001497/sushil